# Put different images per page into the same image element in Jasper Reports

Tags: java, jasper-reports

So, I have a list of image inputstreams to be more precise it is wrapped into an Object like this

```
public class DeliveryBarcodeWrapper {

    private Delivery delivery;
    private InputStream barcode;
```

I have a main report with a detail band in which there is a subreport. I pass the DeliveryBarcodeWrapper list to this subreport as a parameter from java. Then in the subreport I have a field like this name: barcode class: java.io.InputStream.
The whole subreport is in another detail band by the way. There is an image element in this subreport with expression: $F{barcode} but it displays the same image on every page. Why? I set the evaluation time to now. Tried with and without lazy option set but nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it was my stupid mistake. It has nothing to do with Jasper Reports, sorry.